# При попытке замапить класс в Hibernate без xml получаю “2QuerySyntaxException: FileEntity is not mapped”

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Всех приветствую.
Пытаюсь замапить сущность (FileEntity) в Hibernate используя метод **.setAnnotatedClasses()** или **.setPackagesToScan()** из класса **LocalSessionFactoryBean**. Ни тот, ни другой метод не работает. В чем моя ошибка? Когда mapping прописан через **hibernate.cfg.xml** все отлично работает.

ApplicationContextConfig.java

```
    @Configuration
        @ComponentScan("com.group.appName")
        @EnableTransactionManagement
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
        public class ApplicationContextConfig {
        
            @Autowired
            Environment environment;
        
            @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
            public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
                return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            }
        
            @Bean(name = "dataSource")
            public DataSource getDataSource() {
                DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
                dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
                dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
                dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
                return dataSource;
            }
        
            @Autowired
            @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
            public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
                Properties properties = new Properties();
        
                properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
                properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
                properties.put("current_session_context_class", 
environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class"));
        
                LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        
                factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
                factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
                factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

                factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.group.appName.model");
        //      или
        //      factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(FileEntity.class);
                
                return factoryBean.getObject();
            }
        
            @Autowired
            @Bean(name = "transactionManager" )
            public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
                HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                    = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
                return transactionManager;
            }
        
            @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
            public CommonsMultipartResolver getCommonsMultipartResolver() {
                CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
                multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520); // 20MB
                multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);  // 1MB
                return multipartResolver;
            }
        }
```

FileEntity.java

```
@Entity
    @Table(name ="files_upload")
    public class FileEntity {
        private String fileName;
        private Byte[] fileData;
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "file_name")
        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }
        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }
    
        @Column(name = "file_data")
        public Byte [] getFileData() {
            return fileData;
        }
        public void setFileData(Byte [] fileData) {
            this.fileData = fileData;
        }
    }
```

application.properties

```
server.port=9090

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/filedb?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=241299

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему.
Дело в том, что в методе getSessionFactory после создания объекта класса LocalSessionFactoryBean первой строкой должен задаваться класс, который мы хотим замапить. То есть правильно создание объекта выглядит вот так:

```
LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    
    factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(FileEntity.class); - первая строка. Задание аннотированного класса.
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
```